# Use of "Ibn" in Arabic names

Tags: arabic, names

I've been given a script where the Persian scholar Ibn Rustah is referred to as "Ibn". As I understand it, "Ibn" is part of the patronymic *nasab* and shouldn't be used as if it were a first name.

Am I understanding it correctly, or is there any situation in which it could be used that way?

In the interests of being able to supply the producers wi an alternative, what would be the proper way to refer to a respected authority? "Ahmad", "Ibn Rustah", some form of honorific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Ibn" means "son of ..." and is never used as a first name (ism) in Arabic. To address or refer to someone just as "Ibn" is a sign of gross ignorance. Ibn Rustah's close family would have called him by his first name Aḥmad. Otherwise his contemporaries would have addressed him as Abū ʽAlī, his kunyā.

Comment: Great, thanks. I thought it looked pretty odd. :-D

Comment: Does it mean that nobody would have addressed him as "Ibn Rustah"?

Comment: @michau. In the classical period a man is addressed either by his ism or his kunyā.

Comment: @fdb So "Ibn Rustah" was used when people spoke of him in the third person? It must have been used in some contexts, otherwise we wouldn't have known that name...

Comment: @michau. Yes, he used it in his own books.

Comment: The “Ibn Rustah” form would be equivalent to a modern “last name” or “family name”.